# Custom loss for coordinate/landmark prediction

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am currently trying to get a landmark predictor running and thought about the loss function.

Currently the last (dense) layer has 32 values with the 16 coordinates encoded as x1,y1,x2,y2,...

Up until now I was just fiddling with Mean Squared Error or Mean Absolute Error losses but thought the distance between the ground truth and the predicted coordinate would be far more expressive of the correctness of the values.

My current implementation looks like:

```
def dst_objective(y_true, y_pred):
    vats = dict()
    for i in range(0, 16):
        true_px = y_true[:, i * 2:i * 2 + 1]
        pred_px = y_pred[:, i * 2:i * 2 + 1]
        true_py = y_true[:, i * 2 + 1:i * 2 + 2]
        pred_py = y_pred[:, i * 2 + 1:i * 2 + 2]
        vats[i] = K.sqrt(K.square(true_px - pred_px) + K.square(true_py - pred_py))
    out = K.concatenate([
        vats[0], vats[1], vats[2], vats[3], vats[4], vats[5], vats[6], vats[7],
        vats[8], vats[9], vats[10], vats[11], vats[12], vats[13], vats[14],
        vats[15]
    ],axis=1)
    return K.mean(out,axis=0)
```

It does seem to work when I evaluate it but it does look "hacky" to me. Any suggestions how I could improve on this?

Answer (score 2):

The same calculation expressed as tensor operations in Keras, without separating the X and Y coordinates, because that's basically unnecessary:

```
# get all the squared difference in coordinates
sq_distances = K.square( y_true - y_pred )

# then take the sum of each pair
sum_pool = 2 * K.AveragePooling1D( sq_distances,
                                   pool_size = 2,
                                   strides = 2,
                                   padding = "valid" )

# take the square root to get the distance
dists = K.sqrt( sum_pool )

# take the mean of the distances
mean_dist = K.mean( dists )
```

Comment: I really like this. Thanks a lot!

This assumes, that the output format is [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]...] right?
Because I used [x1,y1,x2,y2...] up until now.

Comment: No, it assumes the way you had it, [ x1, y1, x2, y2, ... ]. 1d convolution as parametrized above will join ones next to each other. You might have to add a 0th dim with size 1, because AveragePooling1D requires a batch dimension as well, not sure.